# Quickbooks Desktop BillPaymentCheckAdd error object not found

Tags: qbxml, qbfc

I am trying to add a $20 payment to a bill. This is from the sample Quickbooks file. However i am getting the error `Object \"3E42-1071498278\" specified in the request cannot be found. "` Any ideas. I have tried multiple things. I have indeed checked that the bill exists. I have included below the generated qbxml from the sdk. I am using version 13 of the sdk and QB version 14. Changing the date has no bearing on the error response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError">
        <BillPaymentCheckAddRq requestID = "0">
            <BillPaymentCheckAdd>
                <PayeeEntityRef>
                    <FullName>Sergeant Insurance</FullName>
                </PayeeEntityRef>
                <APAccountRef>
                    <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
                </APAccountRef>
                <TxnDate>2017-01-21</TxnDate>
                <BankAccountRef>
                    <ListID>20000-933270541</ListID>
                    <FullName>Checking</FullName>
                </BankAccountRef>
                <RefNumber>11000</RefNumber>
                <Memo>786-35 Sample</Memo>
                <ExchangeRate>1.000000</ExchangeRate>
                <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                    <TxnID>3E42-1071498278</TxnID>
                    <PaymentAmount>20.00</PaymentAmount>
                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
            </BillPaymentCheckAdd>
        </BillPaymentCheckAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says the transaction with that ID cannot be found.  You may see the transaction in QB, but how do you know that the transaction you are looking at in QB has that ID?  QB does not think it does.

I would expect to see a BillToPayQueryRq and pulling the transactionID out of the BillToPayQueryRs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the payeeEntityRef matches the Bill Txn. You can provide a valid TxnID but if it is not tied to the proper Payee QB will give a TXNID not found error.